# how to to view/create kylin cube's hbase table without encoding

Tags: hadoop, hbase, kylin

I tried to visualize kylin cube's hbase  data. Currently it shows the encoded data. How can i view/create it in normal text.

Apache Kylin Version 2.5
Hadoop 3

Thanks & Regards
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Kylin saves encoded data in HBase for maximum storage efficiency; To view the origin data, please use SQL to query Kylin. Kylin will convert the SQL query to HBase access and then decode the data. You can use Rest API, JDBC, ODBC drivers to connect with Kylin.